# How to add a Model Primary Key which is INT, to an ActionLink LinkText

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add an ActionLinnk where the text will the Persons ID. However, i'm getting an error sayig that 'can't convert int to string'

This works because Fullname is a string

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.FULLNAME, "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
```

This does not because ID is an INT.

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.ID, "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
```

I tried wrapping in quotes but no luck. I could also use razor to convert to string then add it back but I think this should be simple to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to string

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.ID.ToString(), "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
```

Comment: damn... I"m so embarrassed!! I am new to MVC but not to ASP.net!!! Thanks very much