# ASP.Net MVC 5:Try to add a model value to Ajax Actionlink target id / div element within a for loop -

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, partial-views

I'm working on a project (quite new to this topic) where users can add multiple addresses for one company.
Now I would like to add a partial view to my side (by click on an action link) to have a possibility to enter multiple phone numbers for each of these addresses.

The empty sub partial (for phone and..) should be placed directly after the address where the action link was clicked (inherent div element is placed there)

For example I have two addesses for company xyz I render two actionlinks and for each an pending div element.

How can I tell my ajax action link to update only the coresponding div within a for loop? I mean, if the first link is clicked the partial view should be rendert at the first div elements position and so on. I have an addressId available to add it to the link and the id of the div.

The partial is returned correct by the controller (checked with Fiddler), but it will not be rendert on the page.
If I remove the reference to my "AddressId" in ActionLink's "UpdateTargetId" and in the placeholder div - everything works fine.

If I check webside source code I have the same "names" (ComRow+1) in targetId and div id - see:

... data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="after" data-ajax-update="#ComRow+1" href="/companyDetails/GetCommunicationEditor/1">Add a new Phone no./Email for this Address...

and:

```
        </div>
        <div id="ComRow+1">

            </div>
```

I found this:

[dynamic update target id in Ajax.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640074/dynamic-update-target-id-in-ajax-actionlink)

but it doesn't work in my case (maybe I'm in a for Loop?)

and this:
[How to add a Model Primary Key which is INT, to an ActionLink LinkText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744446/how-to-add-a-model-primary-key-which-is-int-to-an-actionlink-linktext)

but the ".ToString()" does'nt solve the problem

What am I doing wrong? Many thank's in advance

This is the code that generates the loop:

```
<div>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EditorAddresses.Count(); i++)
    {

        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EditorAddresses[i])

        //Start - render link to add template for the new address
        <div>

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Add a new Phone no./Email for this Address...",
       "GetCommunicationEditor", new { @id = Model.EditorAddresses.ElementAt(i).AddressId },
       new AjaxOptions
       {
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
           UpdateTargetId = "ComRow+" + Model.EditorAddresses.ElementAt(i).AddressId.ToString(),
       });

        </div>
        //End - render link to add template for the new address



        <div id="ComRow+@Model.EditorAddresses.FirstOrDefault().AddressId.ToString()">

            </div>

        //<div id="ComRow+<%=Model.EditorAddresses.ElementAt(i).AddressId%>"></div>

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself! I removed the string element "ComRow".

I modified the Ajax Actionlink:

UpdateTargetId =  Model.EditorAddresses.ElementAt(i).AddressId.ToString(),

The result is: data-ajax-update="#1" (in "view source code" for website)

And I also changed the code of the "div id" to:

id="@Model.EditorAddresses.ElementAt(i).AddressId.ToString()"

With the result:

id="1" if I look at the website source code

P.S. There was also a mistake in the posted code for the div element "...FirstOrDefault().." was wrong. The right way is to use "...ElementAt(i)..".

I think the problem was, that the div id does not accept a "+"

Maybe this helps somebody